# How to inline a Call?

Tags: c#, linq, compilation, linq-expressions

How can I retrieve the body of a defined method and convert it directly to a LINQ Expression?

---

For example this method is defined (in `Program.cs`):

```
public static void InlineMethod(string message)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
    Debug.WriteLine(message);
}
```

And the following represents the LINQ Expression:

```
var method = typeof(Program).GetMethod(nameof(InlineMethod))!;

var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string));
var call = Expression.Call(method, param);
var block = Expression.Block(call);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(block, param);

((Action<string>)lambda.Compile())("Hello World");
```

This works of course because the called method is compiled as a call:

```
.Block() {
    .Call Solution.Program.InlineMethod($var1)
}
```

The goal is to dynamically (even if the method body changes) retrieve the body of the `InlineMethod` and produce (in this example) the following compile results:

```
.Block() {
    .Call System.Console.WriteLine($var1);
    .Call System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($var1);
}
```

Comment: "*The goal is to dynamically (even if the method body changes) retrieve the body of the InlineMethod and produce (in this example) the following compile results:*" -- no can do. You can't inspect the contents of a compiled method at runtime

Comment: (Well, you *can* get the body of the method as a byte stream representing IL, and then parse that to opcodes, and parse them to the equivalent C#, then create the equivalent expression.... But that's a very large amount of work!)

Comment: Why are you in this situation? Anything is possible, but there are a lot battles not worth fighting

Comment: I'm currently working on some high performance serializers with custom converters. These converters have read / write methods and these should be inlined to remove unnecessary dependencies (converter instances) and speed up the conversion process a bit.

Comment: Thank you @canton7. Since this is not possible without a huge amount of work, I will probably have to discard this approach and find a way to avoid this problem.

Comment: Just make custom converters to return LambdaExpression. Then you can extract body. It is common practice.